# Coverting epoch time value into a timestamp(6) in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

How do I covert epoch time value into a timestamp(6) in teradata ?

Lets take 1336987231051 as the example epoch time ( note this is in milliseconds, where as epoch time is in seconds), I did something like this

```
// miliseconds epoch time 
select cast(1336987231051 as timestamp(6))

// seconds epoch time 
select cast((1336987231051/1000) as timestamp(6))
```

and I get this error message for both of the above select statements :

```
[Error] Script lines: 12-12 ------------------------
[Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 13.10.00.31] [Error 5407] [SQLState HY000] Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval.
```

I verified in http://www.epochconverter.com/ that 1336987231051 is valid epoch time.

What is the right sql for this in teradata ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    cast(cast(700101 as date) + seconds_from_epoch / 86400 as timestamp(6)) +
        (seconds_from_epoch mod 86400) * interval '00:00:01' hour to second
from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to convert EPOCH to TERADATA TIME.

```
SELECT
   1336987231051/1000 as unix_epoc_time   ,
   to_timestamp(unix_epoc_time) utc,
   cast(cast(utc as char(19))||'+00:00' as timestamp(0) with time zone) AT LOCAL    
;
```

1. If your epoch is 10 digit, you don't need `/1000`.
2. Remember, Unix time is in UTC.
3. Your system will treat this "utc" as local. So, let us make it understand that it is UTC by adding "+00:00" and then convert it to your LOCAL using `AT LOCAL` OR using either of these "America Central" , "America Eastern" , "America Mountain" etc.